# PHP: while (time() < time()+2;){ echo "why does this not work ?"};

Tags: php, time, while-loop

```
$zeit = time();
$zeit60 = time()+2;

while ($zeit < $zeit60){
sleep (1);
echo time();
}
```

why does this not work ?

Thanks for Answers!

Comment: It works, but will sleep indefinitely because you are never incrementing `$zeit`.

Comment: Probably you mean to either do `$zeit++` in the end of the loop, or instead do `while (time() < $zeit60) {}`

Comment: use $zeit60 = $zeit + 2 each time you call time() will be different. and before ending the while loop use $zeit++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will print the time every second... forever. Because the condition is essentially `while x < x+2`, which is of course true ∀ x ∈ ℝ

You probably should update the value of `$zeit`, so that after the time expires your loop will exit.

That said, unless you have particularly complex code, it may be sufficient to do the following:

```
$seconds = 2;
while($seconds) {
    sleep(1);
    echo time();
    $seconds--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop will run forever because you are setting the time to a variable.

It would be the same as saying:

```
$a=1;
$b=$a+1;
while($a<$b){}
```

The value of `$a` will never change, therefore you are stuck in infinity forever.
If you have a fixed "wait time" (`$zeit60`), then you can effectively use `time()`:

```
$zeit60 = time()+2;

while (time() < $zeit60){
    sleep (1);
    echo time();
}
```